# read all sheets excels in python

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

I have many excel files in a folder. I want to load all sheets except the first sheet into a dataframe. Each excel has different number of sheets. For example I have E1.xlsx, E2.xlsx. E1 has 5 sheets, and E2 has 9. I need to load sheet 1,2,3,4 from E1, and 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 from E2 (without sheet 0).

```
filenames = glob.glob( "/*.xlsx")
d = []

for filename in filenames:
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, index_col=None, sheet_name=1) # don't know how to set sheet number
    d.append(df)

data = pd.concat(d, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

I have my code here, but don't know how to set the sheet number. (the column in sheet is totally different from other sheet, I think it's not a good choice to read all sheets and delete)

Comment: Hi, sheet is supposed to be zero-indexed by default (integer). Look at this [doc for read_excel under sheet_name](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```py
import glob
import pandas as pd

filenames = glob.glob( "/*.xlsx")
d = []
not_req_sheets = [0]

for filename in filenames:
    xl = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
    for sheet_name in xl.sheet_names:
        if sheet_name not in not_req_sheets:
            df = xl.parse(sheet_name, index_col=None)
            d.append(df)

data = pd.concat(d, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I will do it this way:

```py
filenames = glob.glob( "/*.xlsx")
d = []

for filename in filenames:
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, index_col=None, sheet_name=None) # Load All Sheets
    df = df[1:] # Only need second to last sheets
    d.append(df)

data = pd.concat(d, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```